# Using openmp libraries on MacOS Catalina

Tags: c, openmp, macos-catalina, xcode12

I wanted to ask you the following question. Something like four months ago, I used on my MacOS Catalina the openmp libraries, successfully compiling and running a simple test code:

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
#pragma omp parallel
    printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

The file was named `hello.c` and it was compiled with the command

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib hello.c -o hello.x
```

It used to work.

Now, I try again the same file and I get the following error message

```
In file included from hello.c:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.1/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/omp.h:18:13: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
#   include <stdlib.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The only thing that changed on my computer was that Xcode was updated since I last used openmp libraries. Now I have Xcode version 12.2. I may guess that some path was changed during the update of Xcode.

Did anyone have the same issue and solved it?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Does it work if you use the version of clang that comes with XCode? From the /usr/local path that looks like a different version.

Comment: The standard C header files are missing. You may need to install the command line Xcode tools or something.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I compile using `clang -fopenmp -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib openmp_parallel_for_example.c -lm -o openmp_parallel_for_example.x` I get the error message `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`. Yes, probably updating Xcode has changed the paths, I'll try to reinstall it.